# Handle Application-Level Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, application-error

I have code(It is found in the Internet) to handle application error. I wrote in Event Log.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Exception myError = null;

           if (HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError() != null)
           {
               string eventLog = "MySite";
               string eventSource = "www.mysite.com";
               string myErrorMessage = "";

               myError = Server.GetLastError();

               while (myError.InnerException != null)
               {
                   myErrorMessage += "Message\r\n" +
                      myError.Message.ToString() + "\r\n\r\n";
                   myErrorMessage += "Source\r\n" +
                       myError.Source + "\r\n\r\n";
                   myErrorMessage += "Target site\r\n" +
                       myError.TargetSite.ToString() + "\r\n\r\n";
                   myErrorMessage += "Stack trace\r\n" +
                       myError.StackTrace + "\r\n\r\n";
                   myErrorMessage += "ToString()\r\n\r\n" +
                       myError.ToString();

                   myError = myError.InnerException;
               }

               if (EventLog.SourceExists(eventSource))
               {

                   EventLog myLog = new EventLog(eventLog);
                   myLog.Source = eventSource;


                   myLog.WriteEntry("An error occurred in the Web application "
                     + eventSource + "\r\n\r\n" + myErrorMessage,
                       EventLogEntryType.Error);
               }
           }
        }
```

This is lines from Event Log:

```
Type    Date         Time       Source         Event             Category
Error   03.04.2012 16:44:41 www.mysite.com  0   "An error occurred in the Web application www.mysite.com

"
Error   03.04.2012 16:43:31 www.mysite.com  0   "An error occurred in the Web application www.mysite.com

"
Error   03.04.2012 16:42:56 www.mysite.com  0   "An error occurred in the Web application www.mysite.com

"
Error   03.04.2012 16:42:56 www.mysite.com  0   "An error occurred in the Web application www.mysite.com

"
Error   03.04.2012 16:42:54 www.mysite.com  0   "An error occurred in the Web application www.mysite.com

"
Error   03.04.2012 16:37:27 www.mysite.com  0   "An error occurred in the Web application www.mysite.com
```

"

As you noted an error occurs approximately once in a second. But information about an error the empty.
What is wrong with this code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line imo

```
while (myError.InnerException != null)
```

You write the detail of the error only if there is a innerexception, but it's not always true

You also forgot to call

```
Server.ClearError();
```

At the end of your processing (but I guess it's a choice)